# Update Array Fields

Tags: mongodb

I have a Document Structure as shown below 
let's say for a tree structure like ORDERS.MAIN_ORDERS.P1, this ;basically created 3 document showing parents for each node

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5362a7fd300400ffbabc3754"),
    "categoryid" : "ORDERS",
    "ancestors" : [],
    "availableLocales" : [ 
        {
            "locale" : "en_US",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "rolledUpCount" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5362a7fd300400ffbabc3755"),
    "categoryid" : "MAIN_ORDERS",
    "ancestors" : [ 
        "ORDERS"
    ],
    "availableLocales" : [ 
        {
            "locale" : "en_US",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "rolledUpCount" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5362a7fd300400ffbabc3756"),
    "categoryid" : "P1",
    "ancestors" : [ 
        "ORDERS", 
        "MAIN_ORDERS"
    ],
    "availableLocales" : [ 
        {
            "locale" : "en_US",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
        "rolledUpCount" : 1
}
```

When a new tree comes in(e;g ORDERS.MAIN_ORDERS.P2) i need to increment the count of all the parents for that categoryid( P2) for that particular locale. how do i do that with mongoQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to update using the following:

```js
db.mycollection.update(
    { "availableLocales.locale" : { "$in": ["en_US"] } },
    { "$inc" : { "availableLocales.count" : 1 } }
})
```

This update uses the [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) and [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operators.

Find collection where availableLocales holds an array containing locale with "en_US" value.

```js
{ "availableLocales.locale" : { "$in": ["en_US"] } }
```

Increment the value of the count field by 1.  Note that you can pass multi:true to update all matching documents, not just one.

```js
{ "$inc" : { "availableLocales.count" : 1 } }
```

Please see the docs for more info on how these works.

--- more info:

Update ORDERS:

```js
db.mycollection.update(
    { 
        "categoryid" : "ORDERS",
        "availableLocales.locale" : { "$in": ["en_US"] }
    },
    { "$inc" : { "availableLocales.count" : 1 } }
})
```

Update MAIN_ORDERS:

```js
db.mycollection.update(
    { "categoryid" : "MAIN_ORDERS", "availableLocales.locale" : { "$in": ["en_US"] } },
    { "$inc" : { "availableLocales.count" : 1 } }
})
```

Hope that this clarifies things further. It should point you in the right direction!

Comment: For the structure ORDERS.MAIN_ORDERS.P2 with locale en_US ,  i need to insert P2 and then Increment the count for ORDERS and MAIN_ORDERS, basically incrementing rolledUpCount and count for that locale for all the parents of P2.

Comment: Please see revised answer -- I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: does not work, i get this 
"
cannot use the part (availableLocales of availableLocales.count) to traverse the element ({availableLocales: [ { locale: "en_US", count: 1 } ]})"

Comment: try: { "$inc" : { "count" : 1 } } instead of { "$inc" : { "availableLocales.count" : 1 } }

Comment: Right, this should do it: { "$inc" : { "availableLocales.$.count" : 1 } }

Comment: I think that would only update the first locale's count - [see here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) for the relevant ticket